# Distinct in node fails using mongojs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Im quite new to node and mongodb, but im trying to write a simple API for a monitoring app. I can list out all aps fine through the `/aps` call, but `/locations` throws a:

```
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                              ^
```

> TypeError: `cb` is not a function

I have a collection with the following Schema:

```
ap = {
"name": apname,
"details": [{
    "apmodel": apmodel,
    "apmac": apmac,
    "apipadd": apipadd,
    "apclientcount": apclientcount,
    "aplocation": aplocation
    }]
}
```

// Get all aps works a charm

```
router.get('/aps', function(req, res, next){
    db.ap_info.find().sort({name: 1}, function(err, aps){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(aps);
    });
});
```

But the following does not work:

```
//Get unique locations with wifi
router.get('/locations', function(req, res, next){
    db.ap_info.distinct('details.aplocation', function(err, results){
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```

Thing is, when i execute `db.ap_info.distinct('details.aplocation')` in mongodb, it works, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [signature](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#dbcollectiondistinctfield-query-callback) for distinct method in mongojs follows

```
db.collection.distinct(field, query, callback)
```

so you need to include the query as the second argument in the function:

```
//Get unique locations with wifi
router.get('/locations', function(req, res, next){
    db.ap_info.distinct('details.aplocation', {}, function(err, results){
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```